# How to isolate one page using "X-UA-Compatible" from Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, x-ua-compatible

I have an application with a master page. The page inherits the master page. Prior to IE9, we had no issues in regards to our image viewer. After some research, I have found that I need to use the "X-UA-Compatible" in the meta tag. However, this issue is only occurring on one page.

If I put `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` in the master page, the problem is solved, but that means the rest of the application will have to use this as well. Is there a way for a single page to use that meta tag without effecting the rest of the application?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, e.g.:

1. put the `Response.AppendHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=8");` to the
   codebehind of that single page
2. Put a placeholder to your masterpage and fill it with the meta tag only on that single page

Comment: I will try solution #1. I tried #2 yesterday and that did not seem to fix the issue. Currently, we made another master page that emulates IE8 and had the page inherit the new master.

Comment: I tried #1, but I may have placed it in the wrong method (I put it in the page's OnInit() function). The new master page seems to have fixed the issue.